# SQL / MySQL / PostGres - returning all columns and records when price has been updated

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with thousands of entries for auction items. Some auction items sell right away, others get re-listed at a subsequent auction and at a lower price. Each auction item entry has a unique id for its entry in the database (so when an item is re-entered, it gets a new listing id), but also has a unique item identifier that does not change with a re-listing.

Also, there are categories of auction items, as well as specific brands and types (e.g. category 'furniture' has a lot of listings, of which manufacturer 'la-z-boy' is one brand, and then 'recliner' is yet a more specific type).

The re-listed items are re-entered in the database with a new unique id and a new price, but the unique item identifier stays the same, and all other columns/attributes stay the same. I can find all the items that have had a price change with:

```
SELECT category, unique_item_identifier FROM auction_listings WHERE category='furniture' GROUP BY unique_item_identifier HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

The problem with this query is that it only returns the unique identifier, category and the count, but I can't view the price changes. Also, if I try to get more specific with the query, e.g.

```
SELECT category, brand, unique_item_identifier FROM auction_listings WHERE category='furniture' GROUP BY unique_item_identifier HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

this fails because: "Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

I want to see all the la-z-boys that have had price changes and then also see what those price changes were. I'd also like to be able to run a query that showed all la-z-boys (regardless of type) that had price changes, so I also want to be able to SELECT category, brand, type WHERE brand='la-z-boy' (and then show all la-z-boys that had price changes, with output including the different prices).

I'm looking for output such as:

```
unique-1 la-z-boy recliner price: $1000 entered on 1/1/2018
unique-1 la-z-boy recliner price: $800 entered on 2/1/2018
unique-2 la-z-boy recliner price: $1,200 entered on 1/1/2018
unique-2 la-z-boy recliner price: $1,050 entered on 2/1/2018
unique-2 la-z-boy recliner price: $950 entered on 3/1/2018
unique-3 la-z-boy couch price: $1,200 entered on 1/1/2018
unique-3 la-z-boy couch price: $1,000 entered on 2/1/2018
```

Thanks in advance - I've read dozens of answers here that are very close to this specific request, but couldn't find this explicitly and was unable to figure out from other answers how to do this.

Comment: `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` is in MySQL, not Postgres, so I removed that tag.  Your question would be much clearer if you provided sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided sample data but hopefully the following will be enough to demonstrate the principal

```
+------+--------+----------+-------------+--------+
| id   | userID | industry | companyName | salary |
+------+--------+----------+-------------+--------+
|    1 |      2 |       55 | abc company |     55 |
|    2 |      2 |       55 | xyz company |     75 |
|    3 |      2 |       56 | 123 company |     85 |
|    4 |      3 |       12 | cjf company |     25 |
|    5 |      4 |       52 | xxx company |     77 |
|    6 |      4 |       65 | yyy company |     99 |
+------+--------+----------+-------------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If in a subquery we identify those with more than 1 salary change we can join back to get the detail

```
select userid,companyname,salary
from uex
where userid in(
select userid
from uex
group by userid having count(distinct salary) > 1
);
+--------+-------------+--------+
| userid | companyname | salary |
+--------+-------------+--------+
|      2 | abc company |     55 |
|      2 | xyz company |     75 |
|      2 | 123 company |     85 |
|      4 | xxx company |     77 |
|      4 | yyy company |     99 |
+--------+-------------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

If you want to select a specific user include a where clause in the sub query

```
select userid,companyname,salary
from uex
where userid in(
select userid
from uex
where userid = 2
group by userid having count(distinct salary) > 1
);
```

Comment: If I run that query and want to specify a specific userid, it returns all the results from the original table. e.g.
`code` select userid,companyname,salary
from uex
where userid=2 in(
select userid
from uex
group by userid having count(distinct salary) > 1
);`code`